# Jpanel on top of an applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jpanel, paint

So what i'm trying to is adding a semi transparent jpanel on top of an applet, so i can paint graphics on top of it, but when i do the jpanel displays the panel under the applet.

Here's some code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds(2, 20, 780, 510);
contentPane.add(panel);
panel.setBackground(Color.RED );
panel.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
Applet app = (Applet) new URLClassLoader(
   new URL[] { new File("./App.jar").toURI().toURL() })
                    .loadClass("Main")
                    .newInstance();
                    app.init();
                    app.start();
                    app.setBounds(2, 20, 780, 510);
                panel.add(app);
                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                panel2.setBounds(10, 11, 760, 488);
                panel2.setVisible(true);
                panel2.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 50));
                panel2.setOpaque(false);
                app.add(panel2);
```

So i tried this with jpanel and jinternalframe and both come up with the same results.

Should i use something else instead of jpanel? Or is there's something wrong with that one.

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't mix AWT and Swing components, and so you should be dealing with JApplets, not Applets. But as for your question, why not simply add the JPanel to the JApplet's contentPane in the JApplet's init method?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.

Yeah, i know :P 

If i add it before the applet init it just creates a panel without any transparency on top of the applet.

Comment: You can add a JPanel to the applet at any time during the applet's run, and you can alter its transparency at your whim. I still am unclear as to why my approach won't work. Can you explain (in your original question) the problem in much greater detail?

Comment: Sorry for late reply again, right now my problem seems to be that it's not setting the color for panel2 if i add it to the applet, and that's why it's not transparent.

If i add it to the panel below i can set the color and get it on top of the applet, but then it ignores the applet.

Comment: @Jixi: consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) to allow us to see your problem for ourselves.

Comment: Just read that "a lightweight JPanel overlaid on top of a heavyweight AWT component cannot be transparent. "

My guess is that that's my problem? If so i'll have to rewrite my classloader, if not then i'll definitely write a more detailed question once i'm not so tired :P

Answer (score 1):

> what i'm trying to is adding a semi transparent jpanel on top of an applet, so i can paint graphics on top of it

Use a [Glass Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) of the JApplet.